# Is there a fuction of a feature to work automatically after the app get live

Tags: react-native, mobile-application, expo-go

I have a small problem with a developer I hired for my client project.

He built the app on React and was running it on Expo go to show me the progress, and he said that google and Facebook signup will be automatically fucntional after the app is live.

When the time came to make it live the started to make demands for extra funds to make it live whereas he never mentioned that prior.

Long story short, I changed the developer and took the code from him, now when the new guy is doing the deployment on App store connect & play store they are rejecting it stating that the Google & Facebook signup is not functional.

And the previous developer keep saying that it will be functional automatically after getting live in both the store he has done that kind of setting with the code.

So I just want to know is there anything like this that he is saying?

Looking for an answer for my questions